# Embeded H2 Database for dynamic files

Tags: spring-boot, h2

In our application, we need to load large CSV files and fetch some data out of it. For example, getting the distinct values from the CSV file. For this, we decided to go with in-memory DB's like H2, as there is no need to store the data in persistent storage. 
However, the file is so dynamic that the columns may not be the same. I need to load the file to the H2 database to a table that is temporary for that session. 
Tech Stack is Spring boot and H2. 
The examples I see on forums is using a standard entity that knows what fields the table has. However my case the table columns will be dynamic 
I tried the below in spring boot

```
public interface ImportCSVRepository extends JpaRepository<Object, String>
```

with

```
@Query(value = "CREATE TABLE TEST AS SELECT * FROM CSVREAD('test.csv');", nativeQuery = true)
```

But this gives unmanaged entity error. I understand why the error is thrown. However I am not sure how to achieve this. Also please clarify if I should use Spring-batch ?

Comment: You better look towards NoSQL dbs like MongoDB for example. RDMS doesn't fit well to "dynamic structures" you described.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`JdbcTemplate`](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/core/JdbcTemplate.html) to manually create tables and query/update the data in them.

[An example of how to create a table with JdbcTemplate](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Spring/UseJdbcTemplateToCreateTable.htm)

Dynamically creating tables and defining new entities (or modifying existing ones) is hardly possible with spring-data repositories and `@Entity`-ies. You probably should also check some NoSQL dbs like [MongoDb](https://www.mongodb.com/) - it's easier to define documents (or key-value objects - [Redis](https://github.com/antirez/redis)) with dynamic structures in them.